# Pretty Print Excel Formulas?

Tags: excel, pretty-print, worksheet-function

Is there a way to pretty print Excel formulas?

I've got a few worksheets of semi-complex formulas to slog through, so this would make my life a bit easier.

I'm just looking to turn something like this

```
AC6+AD6+(IF(H6="Yes",1,IF(J6="Yes",1,0)))+IF(X6="Yes",1,0)
```

into something more readable without manually doing it in Vim or the like. Excel does do color-matching on the parentheses, but it's still all mashed together on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This VBA code will win no awards, but it's O.K. for quickly looking at typical formulas. It just does what you'd do with parens or separators manually. Stick it in a code module and call it from the VBA immediate window command line. (EDIT: I had to look at some formulas recently, and I improved on what was here from my original answer, so I came back and changed it.)

```
Public Function ppf(f) As String
    Dim formulaStr As String

    If IsObject(f) Then
        Debug.Assert TypeOf f Is Range

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = f

        formulaStr = rng.Formula
    Else
        Debug.Assert VarType(f) = vbString

        formulaStr = f
    End If

    Dim tabs(0 To 99) As Long

    Dim tabNum As Long
    tabNum = 1

    Dim tabOffset As Long

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String
    For i = 1 To Len(formulaStr)
        c = Mid$(formulaStr, i, 1)

        If InStr("({", c) > 0 Then
            ppf = ppf & c

            tabNum = tabNum + 1
            tabs(tabNum) = tabs(tabNum - 1) + tabOffset + 1
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        ElseIf InStr(")}", c) > 0 Then
            tabNum = tabNum - 1
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & c & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        ElseIf InStr("+-*/^,;", c) > 0 Then
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & c & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        Else
            ppf = ppf & c

            tabOffset = tabOffset + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

If you call it like so:

```
?ppf([q42])
```

you don't have to worry about escaping your double quotes and so on. You'll get output that looks like this:

```
AC6+
AD6+
(
 IF(
    H6="Yes",
    1,
    IF(
       J6="Yes",
       1,
       0)
    )
 )
+
IF(
   X6="Yes",
   1,
   0)
```

You can also call it with a plain string.

Comment: This is great, thanks! One question, am I supposed to call this from a cell? It doesn't like the **[cell].formula** part for some reason. If I copy the literal formula though, it works great!

Comment: You'd have to tweak it for calling from a cell. As is, you'll just get back the string argument plus some unprintable characters because Excel doesn't treat the CR and LF the way VBA does. The ?ppf([q42].formula) would be what you type in the immediate window in the VBA development environment. '?' is just short for 'Debug.Print', and the brackets are short for 'Application.Evaluate(<string>)', so [q42] evaluates to the range $Q$42. Obviously, you will find that this routine fails to print the way you want in all kinds of cases, but it's adequate for quick inspection of your routine formulas.

Comment: To call it from a cell, change the vbCrLf to vbLf, and set the cell you call it from to display wrapped text. You could also make the function take a range argument and then grab it's formula or formulaArray property.

Comment: Oh, you mentioned calling it from the immediate window at the top of the answer...sorry, missed that. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 11):

Try Excel Formula Beautifier http://excelformulabeautifier.com/.  It pretty prints (aka beautifies) Excel formulas.

(I help maintain this, always looking for feedback to make it better.)

Comment: This is just for readability, right? You can't paste the formulas with line breaks back into Excel? Anyway, thanks very much for your great tool!

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, by far the easiest way to do this is to install Microsoft's own Advanced Formula Environment. As well as pretty printing formulas (which can then be copy-pasted into the regular formula bar), it has a host of other features. Go to 'Insert' tab, 'Get Add-ins', search 'Excel Labs'.

I'll also heartily recommend the 'Formula Forge' add-in as a replacement for Evaluate Formula. It makes difficult formulae much, much easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the above code snippet now also handels quoted characters differently, which means, it leaves them alone and doesn't let them effect the indenting if they are inside a string like:

```
"This ({)},;+*-/ won't lead to a linebreak"
```

It is controlled by the boolean variable bInsideQuotes.
It also uses

```
.FormulaLocal
```

to make it possible for Endusers to see something they know.

```
Public Function prettyPrintFormula(f As Variant) As String
    Dim formulaStr As String
    Dim ppf As String

    If IsObject(f) Then
        Debug.Assert TypeOf f Is Range

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = f

        formulaStr = rng.FormulaLocal
    Else
        Debug.Assert VarType(f) = vbString

        formulaStr = f
    End If

    Dim tabs(0 To 99) As Long

    Dim tabNum As Long
    tabNum = 1

    Dim tabOffset As Long

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String
    Dim bInsideQuotes As Boolean
    bInsideQuotes = False
    For i = 1 To Len(formulaStr)
        c = Mid$(formulaStr, i, 1)

        If InStr("""", c) > 0 Then
            bInsideQuotes = Not bInsideQuotes
        End If
        If InStr("({", c) > 0 And Not bInsideQuotes Then
            ppf = ppf & c

            tabNum = tabNum + 1
            tabs(tabNum) = tabs(tabNum - 1) + tabOffset + 1
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        ElseIf InStr(")}", c) > 0 And Not bInsideQuotes Then
            tabNum = tabNum - 1
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & c & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        ElseIf InStr("+-*/^,;", c) > 0 And Not bInsideQuotes Then
            tabOffset = 0

            ppf = ppf & c & vbCrLf & Space(tabs(tabNum))
        Else
            ppf = ppf & c

            tabOffset = tabOffset + 1
        End If
    Next i
    prettyPrintFormula = ppf
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue by using the VS Code [sql-formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.vscode-sql-formatter) extension. I simply paste my formular to a sql file and format with the sql-formatter.

When I put this to file

```py
{=IFERROR(INDEX(names,SMALL(IF(groups=$E5,ROW(names)-MIN(ROW(names))+1),COLUMNS($E$5:E5))),"")}
```

It comes out like that:

```py
{ = IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    NAMES,
    SMALL(
      IF(groups = $ E5, ROW(NAMES) - MIN(ROW(NAMES)) + 1),
      COLUMNS($ E $ 5 :E5)
    )
  ),
  ""
) }
```

Its not perfect but acceptable for my taste. And this can be copied and used back into Excel / google sheets.