# IDE-like solution for Excel formulas

Tags: excel, ide

I'm making a complicated spreadsheet using some formulas with lots of nested `if` statements and I'm wondering if there is a good IDE-like solution for it. It just gets really complicated after a while and knowing where the parentheses close and remembering which `if` statement I'm in can be confusing after a while.

I've tried just pasting it in NetBeans as well as in Notepad+ and that helps with the parentheses and if I white-space it right then that helps me remember which if statement I'm in. However, I'd like a better solution

I know that whatever I'm trying to do can be done a million times more efficiently using VBA, but I don't want to do that and that's not the purpose of this question.

I doubt it'd be possible, but if anyone found me something that would do some [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense)-like functionality, that'd be awesome.

Comment: How about splitting the formula in several steps (nested ifs), each in one cell? Writing the formula in an external IDE is great but when it comes to using / maintaining the spreadsheet, it will be very cumbersome.

Comment: This is way less than what you're asking for, but I do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1447343/58845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Notepad++. I found that it was the best solution I could find. For any interested, here's my final formula... Kind of a mess. It was for a [hourly pay spreadsheet](http://blog.kentcdodds.com/2012/05/06/hourly-pay-spreadsheet/) thing I was doing for fun/experience/whatever.

```
=if(
    row()>=($J$4+2)
    , ""
    , if(
        row() = 2
        , if(
            or(
                MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9) = "Sat"
                , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9) = "Sun"
            )
            , if (
                MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9) = "Sat"
                , if (
                    $J$8="No"
                    , if (
                        $J$9="No"
                        , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3)+2, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)+2
                        , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3)+1, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)+1
                    )
                    , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)
                )
                , if (
                    $J$9="No"
                    , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3)+1, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)+1
                    , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)
                )
            )
            , MID(TEXT(datevalue($J$3), "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue($J$3)
        )
        , if(
            or(
                isnumber(
                    search(
                        "Sat",A1
                    )
                )
                ,isnumber(
                    search(
                        "Fri"
                        , A1
                    )
                )
            )
            ,if(
                isnumber(
                    search(
                        "Sat"
                        , A1
                    )
                )
                ,if(
                    $J$9="No"
                    , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+2, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+2
                    , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1)
                , if(
                    isnumber(
                        search(
                            "Fri"
                            , A1
                        )
                    ),
                    if (
                        $J$8="No"
                        , if (
                            $J$9="No"
                            , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+3, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+3
                            , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+2, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+2
                        )
                        , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1
                    ),
                )
            )
            , MID(TEXT(datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1, "ddEE"),3,9)&" - "&datevalue(right(A1,len(A1)-5))+1
        )
    )
)
```